# can someone help me debug my scheme code

Tags: list, sorting, scheme

I want to write a simple function (highest L k), which take a list and interger K>0, return a new list with k highest numbers.
(highest '(6 7 8 5 3 2) 3) give (6 7 8)

```
(define (highest L k)
  (if (= k 0)
   '()
(cons (highesthelper (car L) L) 
  ((highest (remove (highesthelper (car L) L) L) (- k 1))))))


(define (remove E L)
 (cond
   ((null? L)'())
   ((= E (car L)) (cdr L))
   (else (cons (car L) (remove E (cdr L))))))

(define (highesthelper Hi L)
  (cond
  ((null? L) Hi)
  ((> Hi (car L)) highesthelper Hi (cdr L))
  (else (highesthelper (car L) (cdr L)))))

(highest '(1 7 4 5 3) 2)
```

I can run the helper and remove function without problem, but the highest function give me bugs, can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information about bugs you are getting

Comment: =: contract violation
expected: number?
given: (5 3)
argument position: lst
other arguments...:
1

Comment: i run it in DrRacket

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed a few simple mistakes. Note in particular the `(> Hi (car L))` case of `highesthelper`.

```
(define (highest L k)
  (if (= k 0)
      '()
      (cons (highesthelper (car L) L) 
            (highest (remove (highesthelper (car L) L) L) (- k 1)))))


(define (remove E L)
  (cond
    ((null? L)     '())
    ((= E (car L)) (cdr L))
    (else          (cons (car L) (remove E (cdr L))))))

(define (highesthelper Hi L)
  (cond
    ((null? L)      Hi)
    ((> Hi (car L)) (highesthelper Hi (cdr L)))
    (else           (highesthelper (car L) (cdr L)))))

(highest '(1 7 4 5 3) 2)
```

Comment: is there any better way to do this problem?

Comment: Not better, but an alternative: Use `sort` to order the elements. Then use `take` to extract the number of elements you need.

Comment: I will try to write one